# How can I use click event on multiple page in the same test cases on Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I use click event on multiple page in the same test cases on Selenium and C#

For example:

Go to Google Homepage.

Search the resulting Test

Click on the Search button, 
The user gets Redirected to the Searched Result page, but when I am trying to select any link it showing error.

```
public void opengoogle()
    {
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.AddArgument("--headless");
        ChromeDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(option);
        try
        {

            wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Click();
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Clear();
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).SendKeys("Test");
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Submit();
        }
        finally {  }
```

Comment: Update the question with the `its showing error`

Comment: First, remove thread.Sleep(). Use :driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
Also with this locator, maybe you must use FindElements(), save in collection. Then try to click on it.

Comment: What do you mean by trying to select any link ? are you trying to click on any link ?

Comment: @cruisepandey. Yes i am trying to select any link

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this **code**:

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArgument("--headless");
ChromeDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(option);
wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));  
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("q")));  
wd.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Test"+Keys.RETURN);  
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("a[href='http://www.speedtest.net/']")));  
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='http://www.speedtest.net/']")).Click();
```

P.S :
1. I'm not good in C# though I've tried to convert a java code to C#. Hope this will be helpful for you.
2. This will always open the speedtest.net website. If you want something else, you can have it by replacing the cssSelector which I have written.

Comment: Yes but I need the solutions in C#  not in java @cruisepandey

Comment: I think the code provided by me would work in C# environment too , Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
public void TestMethod1()
    {      
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.AddArgument("--headless");
        ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        try
        {
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.lk/");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30));
            IWebElement searchTextField= wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("lst-ib")));
            searchTextField.SendKeys("Test");
            IWebElement searchButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".lsb")));
            searchButton.Click();
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains("Test"));
            IWebElement searchResultLink= wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[href='http://www.speedtest.net/']")));
            searchResultLink.Click();
        }
        finally { }
    }
```

You can try above code.
It explains following process.

- First move to Google search page.
- Insert "Test" in to search text field.
- Then click on Google search button.
- After Navigate to search results page, click on "www.speedtest.net" link.